# How can you tell the version of Ubuntu on a system in a .sh (bash) script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

So I am trying to create a bash/executable, and it in I need to know the version number of Ubuntu on the system. All the ways I have found online consist of `lsb_release -r`, however I cannot output this into a variable.

Is there any way to get the current version of Ubuntu and save as a variable in a shell executable?

Comment: Yes, I do appreciate it. Sorry, I wasn't aware there was documentation on this. I appreciate it anyhow

Comment: Yes, I have done it. Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
Var=$(lsb_release -r)
echo "$Var"
```

Should do the trick.

For the numeric portion only add this:

```
NumOnly=$(cut -f2 <<< "$Var")
echo "$NumOnly"
```

---

### The `lsb-release` variables file

`/usr/bin/lsb_release` is a Python script. It's a short script that serves as a good introduction to the python language. As others mentioned, a shorter way to get the version number only is with `lsb_release -sr`.

The `/etc/lsb-release` file defines environmental variables with the same information provided by the `lsb_release -a` command:

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS"
```

You can include these environment variables at anytime using `. /etc/lsb-release`. To test in your terminal:

```
$ . /etc/lsb-release

$ echo $DISTRIB_RELEASE
16.04

$ echo $DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION
Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
```

Comment: so yes thank you, it does work, it outputs `Release:                        18.04`. However is there a way to just get the number? I want to be able to use this variable in an if/else function in the script. The purpose of the if/else is to download the correct version of my application for the distro of ubuntu.

Comment: Ah nevermind. @user68186 solved my issue. Thank you guys so much!

Comment: I was going to write the answer but you beat me to it! :-) I am happy to contribute.

Comment: @a.mosallaei alternatively, `NumOnly=$(lsb_release -r | cut -f2)`

Comment: Huh, @RonJohn sounds good

Comment: @a.mosallaei a word of caution - if you're just using the number part and ignoring everything else, this script is going to have weird results on any non-Ubuntu machine (including many Ubuntu-based distributions that are Ubuntu "compatible" but have their own names and versioning); you might need to verify if the lsb_release result starts with "Ubuntu" before using the number.

Comment: No, I understand @Peteris, the only compters that my executable will be used on are Ubuntu machines.

Comment: @Peteris A reverse warning; machines that are **Ubuntu** might fail that proposed test because they say "Mint" or "Budgie" or something like that.

Comment: @a.mosallaei You say that your executable will only be used on Ubuntu computers. How do you know that? It is better to have a failsafe that exits if the distro is not Ubuntu. Trust me, users will try to crash your program.

Comment: @KryštofPíštěk I'm looking at the code for `screenfetch` this morning and it is 400 lines to get distribution name and version number. The code covers 52 of the most popular Linux distributions as of 2015. To be fair, our question here explicitly states **Ubuntu** version in the title.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I am in no way telling anyone to support more distros. However, if you intend the script to only run on Ubuntu, a check would be beneficial.

Comment: That is a good idea. We have not implemented a check, just a warning before install that the script should be ran on Ubuntu. However, I am aware of how to make an Ubuntu check now with the help of you guys, and will consider implementing it. Thanks @KryštofPíštěk

Answer (score 12):

An alternative is to use the `/etc/os-release` file instead. This is formatted as a list of shell variables:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

So an easy way of parsing it is to simply [`source`](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x237.html) the file:

```
$ . /etc/os-release

$ echo $NAME
Ubuntu

$ echo $VERSION
18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)

$ echo $PRETTY_NAME
Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS


$ echo $VERSION_ID
18.04
```

To avoid setting all these variables unnecessarily, you can source the file in a [subshell](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html), echo the variable you need and exit the subshell:

```
$ ( . /etc/os-release ; echo $VERSION_ID)
18.04
```

Alternatively, you can always just parse the file directly:

```
$ grep -oP 'VERSION_ID="\K[\d.]+' /etc/os-release 
18.04
```

Comment: Note that for Ubuntu derivatives, the version info might refer to the downstream version (e.g. I've got VERSION_ID="18.3" and VERSION_CODENAME="sylvia" for my Mint box). UBUNTU_CODENAME should be correct, though.

Comment: subshell is the most robust way to do this, right?

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude probably, yes.

Answer (score 11):

The [`lsb_release`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/lsb_release.1.html) command supports an `-s` (or `--short`) option to print just the information you ask for and not the header that says what kind of information that is.

To get just the version number it is thus sufficient to run:

```bash
lsb_release -sr
```

For example, on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, that outputs:

```
18.04
```

As with the method in [WinEunuuchs2Unix's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1162492/22949), it is still reasonable to use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) to assign this output to a shell variable. Supposing you wanted the `ver` variable to hold the release number:

```bash
ver="$(lsb_release -sr)"
```

With `-s`, there's no need to parse out the number with [`cut`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/cut.1.html), [`sed`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/sed.1.html), [`grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/grep.1.html), [`awk`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/mawk.1.html), more complex forms of [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), or the like.

In this usage, the [`"` `"` quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes) are optional, but I generally suggest quoting [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) and other [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions) except when there is a reason not to.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I never understood the -s, but you explained it perfectly! Appreciated

Answer (score 7):

Short and simple `lsb_release` commands.

- To print version only

  ```
  lsb_release -sr
  ```

  Output:

  ```
  18.04
  ```
- To print description

  ```
  lsb_release -sd
  ```

  Output:

  ```
  Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
  ```

#### About flags used here:

```
-s   show requested information in short format
-r   show release number of this distribution
-d   show description of this distribution
```

Answer (score 1):

Shortening [WinEunuuchs2Unix](https://askubuntu.com/users/307523/wineunuuchs2unix) [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162491/how-can-you-tell-the-version-of-ubuntu-on-a-system-in-a-sh-bash-script/1162492#1162492) a bit:

```
distro=$(lsb_release -i |cut -f2)
echo "${distro,,}"

os_version=$(lsb_release -r |cut -f2)
echo "${os_version}"
```

On Ubuntu 20.04, the following is shown:

```
ubuntu
20.04
```